# Bash nested if statements with several conditions

Tags: bash, if-statement, nested

I'm currently struggling on nested if statements in Bash.
Here's what I'm currently trying to do :

```
if [[ `echo "$command" | cut -d "_" -f 2` == "CAPTURE" ]]; then
    if [[ "$status_general" != "Capturing" && "$status_capture" != "Running" ]]; then
        if [[ `echo "$command" | cut -d "_" -f 3-` == "" ]]; then
            *Further instructions here...*
```

I've checked everything, from if statements proper closure to even trying with several other expressions, but upon running my script and entering the second if statement (the one with 2 expression to check), Bash outputs :

```
line 198: [[ Idle : command not found
```

"Idle" is actually the initial value of the `$status_general` variable, but why on earth isn't the test built-in `[[` not evaluating what's inside the brackets ?
Is my syntax wrong ?

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your spaces (specifically *that* one) isn't actually a space. Erase and retype it.

Comment: Thank you ! You saved me from a few more hours of research for such a silly error... Nice job looking at the `<span class="pln">&nbsp;</span>`!

Answer (score 0):

Not answering your question, just a matter of style. Instead of doing

```
echo "$command" | cut -d "_" -f 2
echo "$command" | cut -d "_" -f 3-
```

You can capture those fields in one command:

```
IFS=_  read -r first second third <<< "$command"
```

Then

```
if [[ $second == "CAPTURE" && $third == "" ]]; then
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Maybe you didn't notice, but I'm using `3-` as a field selector inside the `cut` command. I actually need to get all the remaining fields after the second one, since they are used for invoking specific commands that might take from 0 to several arguments.
Unfortunately, I don't think I can use your solution here (although it might be definitely useful !).

Comment: @SonicGold, yes I did notice. the `read` command will put the 3rd and *all* following fields in the `third` varaible.